# What differences are there in the gameplay and quality of Superliminal on the different consoles?

Tags: version-differences, superliminal

I checked the *Superliminal* user scores on Metacritic:

- Xbox One: 9.6, 1834 ratings
- Switch: 9.5, 1308 ratings
- PC: 7.7, 209 ratings
- PS4: 6.8, 52 ratings

I feel that the gap between these scores is large. If the game is the same on all consoles, then I would not expect a 2-point gap. For the PC, the average should already balance out at 209 ratings. Also, there is a direct correlation between the number of ratings and the score.

Maybe the reason is that *Superliminal* does function differently on different consoles. Therefore, I would like to know what differences there are in gameplay and the quality of the game on the different consoles.